Why doesn't Jupyter notebook print the mathematical symbol input in markdown?
On Coursera (algorithms course from CU), I tried to input theta in the Jupyter notebook in Coursera but it doesn't show the symbol when I click the save icon (floppy disk icon)
 $\theta (n X k-1 + ...) = $\theta (n*k^2)


I expected to see the mathematical symbol. When is the markdown script interpreted again?
Update: On my local Jupyter in VS Code, I see

So the second theta symbol is not showing

You have to 'run' the markdown cell for it to render. Easiest way is to click on it and press Shift + Enter. Otherwise you are leaving it in editing mode without running it and it won't render. The save button doesn't control or relate to executing cells; it just saves current contents of your file.

@Wayne I clicked on the cell and pressed Run in the menu. I also tried Shift+Enter but I did not see any difference. $\theta (n X k-1 + ...) = $\theta (n*k^2)

@Wayne see screenshot in edited OP running in VS Code

Oh, I see another problem then. I think what is meant to happen (but I'm not on a machine where I can test right now, so keep that in mind...) is that the first dollar symbol starts the signal that you going to follow with  LaTeX and then the final dollar sign is meant to signal the end. So you 'closed' the LaTeX before your second theta. (I'l try to add references for that later.) I'm not following what you expect it to do or what you want it to look like? Is there any place this works as you expect? Did you try other examples?

I expected to see two theta symbols.

Wouldn't you use the following?:
 $\theta (n X k-1 + ...) = \theta (n*k^2)$


The $ signals the start of the inline LaTeX and a second $ is used to end it
Looking at the result of the following rendered in Jupyter markdown may give you a better idea.
This is before inline LaTeX. $\theta (n X k-1 + ...) = \theta (n*k^2)$ This is after inline LaTeX.

For more information, see under 'Inline Typesetting (Mixing Markdown and TeX)' here in the Jupyter Notebook Documentation.

If you want the formula centered in the middle of page:
This is before centered LaTeX. $$\theta (n X k-1 + ...) = \theta (n*k^2)$$ This is after centered LaTeX.

Note there the starting signal is double dollar sign. And then it is ended with other instance of double dollar sign.
See the bottom of here under 'Other Syntax' here in the Jupyter Notebook Documentation.

(−1+...)=(∗2) that worked! thanks especially for the explanation. Is there a site (without having to download potential malware) you can recommend where I can input latex and get the symbols?

I'm not quite sure what direction you are looking to go? Some suggestions: resources detailed here, Equation Editor, latex2sympy. You can always use JupyterLite to test things out by going to the Try Jupyter page and clicking on the top three tiles( JupyterLab, Jupyter Notebook, & JupyterLite) to get versions that will run deep inside your browser and not remotely.

There are Latex expressions here in the errata for my textbook and I have no idea what the symbols are https://www.algorist.com/errata-old

I wanted to display as an equation, a^(logb(n)) = n^(logb(a))

Okay, I think you want latex2sympy. Or, IPython.display's Math(), see here. For latex2sympy, you need to install it into Jupyter that has a typical ipykernel, i.e., JupyterLite won't presently work. So go to here and press the first 'launch binder' badge on the page to start a temporary, remote session without  you needing to install anything on your machine. ...

 When that temporary session starts up, ope a new notebook and run %pip install latex2sympy2 and then when it completes restart the kernel. Then you can run the code under Usage at the latex2sympy repo, or for  IPython.display's Math() an example here Note that you can try things with Sympy itself here without installing anything (or in JupyterLite). Also related, for further back to the formula from the sympy/math form, also see ...

 latexify_py, with examples here. Aso see resources here for more.

At Sympy, when I input the expression I get: `--------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 a^(logb(n))
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
$$
$a^(logb(n))$
Cell In[3], line 1
$a^(logb(n))$
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Yes, that line is not Sympy syntax or even Python. Sympy is Python. But this is a new question that deserves a new post if you cannot find the answer. For one reason it is a new post is because there's no way to share code and I cannot tell what you are doing. I will add I I was only referring to Sympy for converting the equation.  It requires using Python to do that. You cannot just paste in markdown like you seem to be doing. And there is lots of sympy code at the Jupyter DIscourse site.
